# Inherit a class to a constructor

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class abc
{
    public abc():this(new pqr())
    {}
}
```

The above code represents that the constructor abc() is inherited by some class.

What does the above code mean?

When to use such code?

Why it is used?

Comment: "represents that the constructor abc() is inherited by some class" It does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The above code represents that the constructor abc() is inherited by some class.

No it doesn't.

It means that the parameterless `abc` constructor chains to the `abc` constructor taking a `pqr`.

So you'd actually have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() : this(new Bar())
    {
    }

    public Foo(Bar bar) // implicit call to parameterless base constructor
    {
        // Do something with bar here
    }
}
```

See my [article on constructor chaining](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more info.

As for when you would want to do this - that's really too broad a question. But as an example, suppose you have a `TimeOfDay` type - you may well want constructors of:

```
public TimeOfDay(int hour, int minute)
public TimeOfDay(int hour, int minute, int second)
public TimeOfDay(int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond)
```

Comment: Jon, Can you please elaborate it with any example.

Comment: Jesus christ, I thought I was writing an answer for C++ question. Mixing things up here.

Comment: Why should i call a different constructor of class abc that takes a new pqr object, where i can directly declare a paramaterised constructor and do job instead of declaring 2 constructors viz. Foo() and Foo(Bar bar)

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt: Well if you *do* only want a parameterized constructor, then do that - but there are times when you want to expose multiple constructors, and chain them together - this is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public abc():this(new pqr())
```

This line means that there is another constructor with a parameter in the **same** class. When you call `new abc()` in your code, you actually call the constructor `new abc(var param)` and give it a certain value (here `new pqr()`).

Answer (score 1):

You code is an (unfinished) example of a *constructors chain*:

```
public class abc {
  // To finish the example, you have to add one constructor more:
  // You can omit ": base()" here,
  // base class constructor will be called by default
  public abc(pqr value): base() {...}

  // Explicit chain: when initializing like that "new abc()"
  // call constructor above "abc(pqr value)" 
  // with "new pqr()" value
  public abc(): this(new pqr()) {}
}
```

You can't inherit *constructors*, but *classes*, e.g:

```
  public class a {
    public a(int value) {...}
  }

  public class b: a {
    // b doesn't inherit any "a" constructors, 
    // (you can't call "b(1)" unless you provide "public b(int value)" constructor)        
    // but can call base class constructor if required
    public b(): base(0) {...}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

constructors cannot `inherit` but `class`es can.

The above code is calling a different constructor of class `abc` that takes a new `pqr` object.

Also, it is used to reuse code in the constructor that takes `pqr` object.

Comment: Aniket, Whats the benefit of doing so?